# How can I refer to a control whose name is determined at runtime?

Tags: delphi

As a kind of self-study exercise, I've made a form which contains six panels in a 2x3 rectangle and I want them to switch between visible and invisible one after another. I'm trying to do so by using a for loop of some kind. I could of course write something like:

```
Panel1.Visible := true;
Panel1.Visible := false;
Panel2.Visible := true;
Panel2.Visible := false;
Panel3.Visible := true;
etc. etc.
```

But this takes quite a lot of typing and is pretty inefficient when I decide I want it to wait for 100ms between each step. For example, I'd then have to edit all the six steps to wait. This is doable for six steps, but maybe another time I want to do it a hundred times! So I'm thinking there must also be a way to use a for loop for this, where a variable varies from 1 to 6 and is used in the object identifier. So it would something like this:

```
for variable := 1 to 6 do begin
Panel + variable.Visible := true;
Panel + variable.Visible := false;
end;
```

Now, this obviously doesn't work, but I hope somebody here can tell me if this is in fact possible and if yes, how. Maybe I can use a string as the identifier? My explanation is probably pretty bad because I don't know all the technical terms but I hope the code explains something.

Comment: The problem is not the help. You need to learn basics of programming, and in this case arrays. You don't form identifiers like that at runtime in a language like Delphi.

Comment: The help function is not useless, but it's just help not tutorial.

Comment: You're not referring a _variable_, you're referring to a Object, more specifically a Component, whose name you determine at runtime. In a compiled language like Delphi, you cannot do that really with a variable, like an integer, only with components, controls or other objects that are stored in a list where you can lookup for them by name.

Comment: @jachguate In fact I wrote that title. In an edit to try to make the question clearer. And in the question, Jim is trying to build variable names at runtime. The responses to the Q explain that's not possible, but the title refelcts the Q I think.

Comment: @David It's OK with me, I was only making a point about the fact, but I didn't change the title also because I think it's useful as a search handle for this case, as some people may reason that way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can loop through the panel's Owner's `Components` array.

```
var
  i: Integer;
  TmpPanel: TPanel;
begin
  { This example loops through all of the components on the form, and toggles the
    Visible property of each panel to the value that is opposite of what it has (IOW,
    if it's True it's switched to False, if it's False it's switched to True). }
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do                  
    if Components[i] is TPanel then                    
    begin
      TmpPanel := TPanel(Components[i]);
      TmpPanel.Visible := not TmpPanel.Visible;     // Toggles between true and false
    end;
end;
```

You can also use the `FindComponent` method, if you want a very specific type of component by name. For instance, if you have the 6 panels, and their names are `Panel1`, `Panel2`, and so forth:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  TmpPanel: TPanel;
begin
  for i := 1 to 6 do
  begin
    TmpPanel := FindComponent('Panel' + IntToStr(i)) as TPanel;
    if TmpPanel <> nil then      // We found it
      TmpPanel.Visible := not TmpPanel.Visible;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The Components array has nothing to do with parentage. For a parent-child relationship, use the Controls array. The Components array deals with the ownership relation.

Comment: I give a +1 for the FindComponent method. I think this one is a method not everybody knows about, and is exactly what they need. Thx Ken!

Comment: There is also `TWinControl.FindChildControl`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a situation where you want to create the controls dynamically at runtime rather than at designtime. Trying to grapple with 6 different variables is just going to be a world of pain. And when you need the grid to be 3x4 rather than 2x3, you'll regret that decision even more.

So, start with a completely blank form. And add, in the code, a two dimensional array of panels:

```
private
  FPanels: array of array of TPanel;
```

Then, in the form's constructor, or an `OnCreate` event handler, you can initialise the array by calling a function like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.InitialisePanels(RowCount, ColCount: Integer);
var
  Row, Col: Integer;
  aLeft, aTop, aWidth, aHeight: Integer;
  Panel: TPanel;
begin
  SetLength(FPanels, RowCount, ColCount);
  aTop := 0;
  for Row := 0 to RowCount-1 do begin
    aLeft := 0;
    aHeight := (ClientHeight-aTop) div (RowCount-Row);
    for Col := 0 to ColCount-1 do begin
      Panel := TPanel.Create(Self);
      FPanels[Row, Col] := Panel;
      Panel.Parent := Self;
      aWidth := (ClientWidth-aLeft) div (ColCount-Col);
      Panel.SetBounds(aLeft, aTop, aWidth, aHeight);
      inc(aLeft, aWidth);
    end;
    inc(aTop, aHeight);
  end;
end;
```

And now you can refer to your panels using cartesian coordinates rather than a flat one dimensional array. Of course, you can easily enough declare a flat one dimensional array as well if you want.

The key idea is that when you are creating large numbers of control in a structured layout, you are best abandoning the designer and using code (loops and arrays).

Comment: +1 I like creating components on the fly in such case. My only advice/concern is that you use `Left,Top,Width,Height` local variables which are named just like some `TMyForm` properties. In such cases, I use either `aLeft` or `lLeft` or just `L, T, W, H: integer` to avoid any scope confusion.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez That's fair criticism.

Answer (score 5):

Use `FindComponent` method of `TComponent`:

```
  for variable := 1 to 6 do begin
    pnl := FindComponent('Panel' + IntToStr(variable));
    if pnl is TPanel then
    begin
      TPanel(pnl).Visible := true;
      TPanel(pnl).Visible := false;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixed my problem. So, the 'is' in line 3 just looks at what kind of object pnl is?

Comment: welcome, "is" operator checks whether an object is of specific type.

Comment: Whilst that looks like it fixes your problem, and it certainly answers the question that you asked, it won't lead to easy to maintain and develop code.

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, FindComponent is the way to go.

But if you just want to modify generic properties for the component, such as visible, position etc, it's not necessary to compare to the type.

This will work just as fine:

```
  for i := 1 to 16 do
  begin
    (FindComponent( 'P' + inttostr(i) ) as TControl).Visible := false;
  end;
```

(NOTE: this is for Delphi 6/ 7, modern versions probably do this in other ways)

Answer (score 0):

**Actually my answer**

If you use a name convention to name your component like

```
 "Mycomponent" + inttostr(global_int)
```

you can use it to find it very easily :

```
function getMyComponent(id:integer) : TComponent;
begin
result := {Owner.}FindConponent('MyComponent'+inttostr(id));
end;
```

You also can make your generated components to interact each other by using `(sender as TComponent).name` to know which other component are related to him.

---

**Exemple**

Following is an example of what you can do with this :

Imagine a pagecontrol where tabs are an interface you want to have multiple time
(for ex, to describe columns in a file with 1 tab = 1 col, and you want to dynamically add tabs).

For our example, we are naming button and edit this way :

```
Button : "C_(column_number)_btn"
Edit   : "C_(column_number)_edi"
```

You can actually refer directly to the edit with a buttonclick, linked at runtime by calling findcomponent :

```
procedure TForm1.ColBtnClick(Sender:TObject);
var nr : string; Edit : TEdit; 
begin
// Name of the TButton.  C(col)_btn
nr := (Sender as TButton).Name;

// Name of the TEdit  C_(column)_edi
nr := copy(nr,1,length(nr)-3)+'edi';

// Get the edit component.
edit := (Form1.Findcomponent(nr) as TEdit);

//play with it
Edit.Enabled := Not Edit.Enabled ;
showmessage(Edit.Text);
Edit.hint := 'this hint have been set by clicking on the button';

//...

end;
```

Of course, you link this procedure to every generated buttons.

If anyone wants to practice with it, you may want to know how to generate the tabsheet and components, here you go :

```
procedure Form1.addCol(idcol:integer, owner : TComponent); // Form1 is a great owner imo
var
pan : TPanel;    // Will be align client with the new tabsheet
c: TComponent;   //used to create components on the pannel
tab : TTabSheet; 
begin
try
  pan  := TPanel.create(owner);
  pan.name := format('Panel_%d',[idcol]);
  pan.caption := '';

  // dynamically create that button
  c := TButton.create(Owner);
  with c as TButton do
  begin
    Name := format('C%d_btn',[idcol]);
    Parent := pan;
    //Top  := foo;
    //Left := bar;
    caption := 'press me';
    OnClick := Form1.ColBtnClick;      // <<<<<<< link procedure to event
  end;

  //create a Tedit the same way

  c := TEdit.create(Owner);
  with c as TEdit do
    Name := format('C%d_edi',[idcol]);
    Parent := pan;
    // other properties


  //  create the tabsheet and put the panel in
finally
  tab := TTabSheet.Create(Parent);
  tab.caption := 'Column %d';
  tab.PageControl := Pagecontrol1;

  pan.Parent := tab;
  pan.Align := alClient;
end;  
end;
```

Generating names to get the component is actually a very good way to have a clean code.

Scrolling through parent - child components in order to find the one you want is actually inefficient and becomes hell if there is many component (in my example, if there is 3, 10 or unknown number of TEdit looping child (brother) components will be ugly.

Maybe this example is useless but It may helps someone, someday.