# increment a variable in while loop? (not an array)

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a lot of EditControls in a dialoge page. They are called Edit1, Edit2, et cetera. Is it possible to get the values from those controls using a while loop like you could with an array? I know for an array you could do something like:

```
begin
// Loop 5 times
  for i := 1 to (10 div 2) do
    ShowMessage(Edit[i].Text); <- here I need to get value of Edit1, Edit2, et cetera
end;
```

How to do this with strings instead of arrays?

Comment: have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13649350/2093077

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me an Undeclared Identifier : 'Component Count' - Probably not supported in FastReport

Comment: You need to use `Form1.ComponentCount` if you are using it in another class rather than owner of edit controls.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like second suggested option there. Again you need to call `From1.FindComponenet`, where `Form1` is owner of edit controls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I refer to a control whose name is determined at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649250/how-can-i-refer-to-a-control-whose-name-is-determined-at-runtime)

Comment: Why does it matter whether it is a while loop or a for loop? That doesn't seem important to you at all. What seems important is that you want to refer to the components by name, a topic that has been covered here hundreds of times. Do some research. However, almost always it is better not to use the name in this way. The approach using arrays it other containers is generally better.

Comment: @vincentkleine Is this Delphi code or a FastReport script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that there is no `ComponentCount`, after all it is a `TComponent` property. If it exists, use this code below and replace the name `Form1` with the name of your `Object Parent of Edits`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
   for i := 0 to Form1.ComponentCount -1 do
      if Form1.Components[i].Name = 'Edit' + IntToStr(i+1) then
         TEdit(Form1.Components[i]).Text := 'NewTextEdit' + IntToStr(i+1);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to search all the TEdit(s) in the form, you can do the following:

```
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to Self.ComponentCount- 1 do
        if Self.Components[i] is TEdit then
            ShowMessage(TEdit(Self.Components[i]).Text);
end;
```

In case your TEdits are placed on other controls (like GroupBoxes, Panel, etc.) and you would like to search just inside those controls then you should do:

```
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to gbx1.ControlCount - 1 do
        if gbx1.Controls[i] is TEdit then
            ShowMessage(TEdit(gbx1.Controls[i]).Text);
end;
```

or you could search in multiple TWinControls:

```
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to Self.ControlCount - 1 do    
    begin    
        //TEdits are in TGroupBox
        if Self.Controls[i] is TGroupBox then
            ReadEdits(TGroupBox(Self.Controls[i]))
        //TEdits are in TPanel
        else if Self.Controls[i] is TPanel then
            ReadEdits(TPanel(Self.Controls[i]))
        else ... (other possible Parent Controls)  
    end
end;

procedure TForm1.ReadEdits(aParent: TWinControl);
var
    i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to aParent.ControlCount - 1 do
        if aParent.Controls[i] is TEdit then
            ShowMessage(TEdit(aParent.Controls[i]).Text)
end;
```