# Delphi: how to get exact name of component with TEdit text

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

Sorry, maybe I couldn't formulate my question clearly. I have a lot of Tpanels in my form. I need get exact name of a TPanel with TEdit.text. for example TEdit.text is 26, instead of using `if panel26.color=clred then ...`, I want `if (Panel+edit1.text).color=clred then ...`

Comment: Hi, Your question not well formed and extremely hard to understand. I personally am not sure what you are asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***FindComponent*** like this:

```
var
  TmpPanel: TPanel;
begin
  TmpPanel := FindComponent('Panel' + edit1.text) as TPanel;
  if TmpPanel <> nil then      // We found it
    if TmpPanel.color=clred then ...
end;
```

source for my answer if you want to dig deeper : [How can I refer to a control whose name is determined at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649250/how-can-i-refer-to-a-control-whose-name-is-determined-at-runtime)

Comment: If you can answer a question by copy/pasting from an answer to another one, then the question is a duplicate and should be closed as such.

Comment: Yes sir. I would, if i could. How can i close it as such? I don't see any option to close the question anywhere. Should i flag it then? For future reference. I'm only here for about one week, so please enlighten me.

Comment: Until you've earned enough rep to cast close votes yourself, you use a flag that indicates it's a duplicate. The flag link is in the lower left corner of the question, below the tags. Once you've earned the close vote privilege, a *close* link will appear in the same location (below the tags).

Comment: I see, so i check the "In need of moderator intervention", explain its a duplicate, then provide link to the question i think its linked to. Thank you kind sir!