# Looking for a way to use arrays for edit (TEdit) field

Tags: delphi

Let's say I have three TEdit fields on a form, and I name them `Name1`, `Name2`, and `Name3`:

```pascal
n     :byte;
names :array[1..3] of string;

names[1]:='Erik'; 
names[2]:='Ole'; 
names[3]:='John';

For n:=1 to 3 do
 Case n of
  1:=name1.text:=names[n];
  2:=name2.text:=names[n];
  3:=name3.text:=names[n];
End;
```

This works, but if you have a lot of edit fields on a form then `case x of` is a bad way, I think.

Does anyone have another way to do this?

I use Delphi 4.0, and I do not have much experience.

It will be fantastic if I could name the edit fields like arrays.

Comment: I wonder if the term Delphi Pascal 4.0 is actually what you mean. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi#Delphi_4_(Codename:_Allegro)

Comment: This is neither valid code, nor valid formatting (or valid English).

Comment: Are you really using a compiler that is over 25 years old?

Comment: Yes, I got it free for many years ago

Comment: Delphi 4 was one of the worst versions ever released. It was totally full of bugs, and no one used it. The only version that was worse was version 8, which was their attempt to produce a .Net version. If you got it free many years ago, you were cheated. Try updating to something that was produced in the current century. Once you've done that, you can write some code that creates a [mre] that demonstrates the issue you're having, and ask a clear, specific question based on that code, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: 'Delphi 4 was one of the worst versions ever released', well previously I used Turbo Pascal  so for me Delphi 4 was a 'Big' update,  but I will try to see what I can afford with my pension, I only use it as my hobby so I will check online if I can upgrade.

Comment: Then you should consider using [Lazarus/FPC](https://www.lazarus-ide.org) because that's entirely free and you're not even bound to Windows (or its 32-bit platform) anymore. I've used D4 decades ago, too (and also at novice level), when it was the latest version - also having a Turbo Pascal past.

Comment: It was a big help, I installed FPC from Lazarus (on Windows 10, 64bit) and made a small program that added some numbers and it work, looking like Delphi !   - thanks for suggestion. Erik

Answer (score 2):

Create an array once (f.e. in the `OnCreate` event) where you assign all the `TEdit`s (or whatever controls in general) so you can access them anytime easily:

```pascal
var
  aEdit: Array[1.. 3] of TEdit;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  aEdit[1]:= Name1;
  aEdit[2]:= Name2;
  aEdit[3]:= Name3;
```

Now, you can easily use this array to save performance when you want to use it in a loop:

```pascal
var
  n: Byte;
  names: Array[1.. 3] of String;
begin
  names[1]:= 'Erik'; 
  names[2]:= 'Ole'; 
  names[3]:= 'John';

  for n:= 1 to 3 do 
    aName[n].Text:= names[n];
```

A different approach is to use [`FindComponent()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent), which has been covered in many questions before, like [How can I refer to a control whose name is determined at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13649250/4299358):

```pascal
var
  n: Byte;
  found: TEdit;
begin
  for n:= 1 to 3 do begin
    found:= FindComponent( 'Name'+ IntToStr( n ) ) as TEdit;
    found.Text:= 'number '+ IntToStr( n );
  end;
```

Comment: Hi Remy, I try to understand your suggestion, what is Name1, Name2, Name3 in formcreate ? Sorry I am not so experience in pascal, Reg. Erik

Comment: I wrote the answer, as indicated by "_answered_". You wrote yourself "_I have three TEdit fields on a form, and I name them `Name1`, `Name2`, and `Name3`_" and now ask "_what is Name1, Name2, Name3_"? Even if you're using an online translation tool you should recognize your own component names.

Comment: The problem with answering very poor questions is that it adds no value to the site.

Comment: I understand that I am "beginner" in pascal so I am not on your level, I notice that Name1 to 3 was used in my example, but in my example it was tedit feild, in your code your already rename my tedit to nEdit1..3,  thats way I ask what it was !

Comment: Yes I get to work, I will now try to do some test, I am sure I can use it now.

Comment: Thanks you so much, and again sorry I am not on your level and I do not give value to the page, Erik